# Laravel 6: Not using column on the where clause

Tags: laravel-6

I want to achieve something like this:

```
select * from my_table where (id = 200 OR 1 = 1)
```

How can I do it in Laravel eloquent?

It's a little bit weird request, but it's necessary because if the value of the request variable passed is 1, then return all records, otherwise return the record where id is equal to that variable.

Comment: Why not just a conditional? Like `$records = $request->input('field') == 1 ? Model::all() : Model::find(200);` (obviously replace variables/hard-coded values with real data).

Comment: that's actually my last resort. But I don't want to duplicate multiple lines of code just to add 1 line of where clause.

Comment: So you'd rather use a non-sensical MySQL clause? Ok then... You can do `whereRaw('(id = 200 OR 1 = 1)')`, substituting `200` and `1` for actual values from input. If you try to use `eloquent`, `where('id', 200)->orWhere('1', '1')`, your query will fail, as `1` is not a column.